CloudFront charges after you invalidate your distribution over 1,000 times, does the count reset each month?
If the amount of invalidations you've created exceed 1,000, CloudFront begins to charge one money for each subsequent invalidation. Does your invalidation count reset each month, or does it continue to rise until it begins to cost one money?
Apologies if this is a dim-witted question, as CloudFront is a rather new tool for me.
Thank you all very much.

Per the pricing documentation page for CloudFront (emphasis mine):

The first 1,000 invalidation paths that you submit per month are free.

So it resets each month.
